# Ant Build - taskdef cannot be found

Tags: java, ant, weblogic, classpath

I am attempting to perform an Ant build to build a web service from a WSDL file for a Weblogic web application. However, I am receiving the following error upon attempting the build:

```
BUILD FAILED 
/<path>/build.xml:19: taskdef class weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.WsdlcTask cannot be found 
using the classloader AntClassLoader[]
```

The taskdefs in the `build/xml` look like this:

```
<taskdef name="wsdlc"
         classname="weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.WsdlcTask"/>
<taskdef name="jwsc"
  classname="weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwscTask" />
<taskdef name="clientgen"
  classname="weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.ClientGenTask" />
<taskdef name="wldeploy"
  classname="weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLDeploy"/>
```

I have also tried to explicitly define the classpath in these taskdefs as follows, with no success:

```
<taskdef name="wsdlc"
           classname="weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.WsdlcTask"
           classpath="/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/weblogic.jar"/>
```

And this is the classpath of the build.xml file:

[image: classpath of build.xml]

I have no clue why I get a "class cannot be found" error... I'm following instructions from [Oracle docs - Building a Web Application from an WSDL file](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/weblogic-server/12.2.1.4/wsget/jax-ws-setenv.html#GUID-0EF675E0-F707-4223-9AD8-C31F123D59B7) for the format of the build.xml file.

Notes:
I am **NOT** executing this build.xml file from the same location the Weblogic server is being run from, as the Weblogic server does not have Ant installed. I am attempting to build it locally, in order to get the web service created, to finally deploy it in an EAR bundle of the WAR file + web service through the Weblogic console.

Comment: Is the jar actually located in `/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/`? Try typing `ls /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/` in your terminal. You need to find the actual path.

Comment: Yes, the jar is indeed in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to set WLS domain environment (setDomainEnv.sh)., otherwise ant cannot find proprietary WLS classes.

(setDomainEnv.cmd for Windows and setDomainEnv.sh for Linux).

to achieve that you need to:

```
source ./setDomainEnv.sh
```

Comment: I ended up installing Ant on the WebLogic server. The instructions in the Oracle documentation mentioned to run setDomainEnv.sh, which is located in ORACLE_HOME/user_projects/domains/domainName - should I have my build.xml and code directory in here as well? Or does it not matter?

Comment: it doesn't matter the location because that script actually adds jar files to the classpath

Comment: Hmm, I see. I seem to still be getting the same error though - taskdef class weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.WsdlcTask cannot be found. Maybe it's an issue with where the Weblogic files are.

Comment: remember to use "source or ." in Linux, just like the example I gave in the answer

Comment: Hi, maybe late comment.. but I am having the same error
Where do you add "source ./setDomainEnv.sh
" ?  In the build.xml file or in the script where you start ?

Comment: That script will add paths and environment variables to your terminal. Therefore it must be executed before executing ant.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just added the "weblogic.jar" to the classpath configuration.
Localized at: [your_directory]\wls\wlserver\sip\server\lib

ECLIPSE: Run as -> Ant Build... -> Classpath(tab) -> Add external Jar's

Comment: Or the OP could have used a relative path AND set base.dir - the first comment on the question actually had the answer (did he really mean a path starting with /).